# Two reference pointing to the same object in memory but works independently in java?

Tags: java, object, reference, this, memory-address

```
public class StackWithLinkedList<P> {

    private Node top = null;

    public StackWithLinkedList(){}

    public void push(P val){
        Node newNode = new Node(val);
        if (this.top != null) {
            newNode.nextLink = top;
        }
        this.top = newNode;
    }

    public void traverse(){

        Node currentNode = this.top;
        while(currentNode != null){
            System.out.println(currentNode.val);
            currentNode = currentNode.nextLink;
        }

    }

    private class Node{

        Node nextLink;
        P val;

        public Node(P val){
            this.val = val;
        }

    }
}
```

Look at this code in the traverse(),

```
Node currentNode = this.top;
```

here an object of type Node is created that points to the already existing **this.top** node object.
So it means, **two references pointing to the same object in memory isn't it?**

But when I use the traverse() method, **both the object works independently as the currentNode gets to Null after traversing but the this.top remains unchanged**, holding all the nodes that have been pushed.

**I tried debugging and i saw this.top has the same memory address as the currentNode.**

[image]

**In the end,**

[image]

**I am not able to figure out why is it?**

Comment: You only set `currentNode` from `this.top` *once,* at the beginning of your `traverse` method.  After that, they're not going to point to the same node.

Comment: Note that "`this.top` remains unchanged, holding all the nodes that have been pushed" is an incorrect statement.  `this.top` refers to the first node in your linked list, and that is all it refers to.

Comment: in traverse() you are updating only currentNode. The other one is not being updated, and remains pointing to this.top

Comment: @Judy1989, Yes, but isn't at the beginning the currentNode pointed to the same object this.top, So two references pointing to the same object,  let me clarify the question, why the this.top isn't becoming null while currentNode does? sorry if the question seem absurd.

Comment: @mockingbird: I have the suspicion that despite often using the correct phrases ("references pointing to same object") you still don't *quite* understand the whole references/objects distinction (and that's not unusual, it is a tricky thing to wrap your head around, even if it isn't super-complicated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are conflating "object" and "reference". For example in the sentence

For example here:

> Look at this code in the traverse(),
>
> ```
> Node currentNode = this.top;
> ```
>
> here an object of type Node is created that points to the already
> existing **this.top** node object.

No object of type `Node` is created here (there is no `new`, that's how you know).

What **is** defined here is a (local) **variable** of type `Node`. And the reference that is stored in `this.top` is also assigned to `currentNode`.

> So it means, **two references
> pointing to the same object in memory isn't it?**

Yes, this part is again correct.

Think of a reference like a sheet of paper. The paper can be empty (i.e. the reference is `null`) or it can have some address written on it (i.e. it points to some object).

Now `currentNode` is a piece of paper that happen to have the same address written on it that `this.top` also has written on it (it's a tiny bit more complicated, because `this` is a piece of paper written on it and if you look at that address then you'll find some other piece of paper labelled `top` that has some address written on it, but that doesn't fundamentally change how this works).

At some point later in the code `currentNode` gets reassigned (i.e. the content of the piece of paper gets changed). First to a *different* address (i.e. the address scribbled out and replaced with another one) and then eventually with `null` (i.e. you scribble out the content and leave it "blank").

But just because you wrote on **that** piece of paper doesn't mean that the *other* piece of paper (found via `this.top`) has changed. There is no reason for to it change: they are two independent pieces of paper that at one point happen to have had the same stuff written on them.

Or put differently: *assigning a new value to* `currentNode` has absolutely no effect on the *object previously referenced by `currentNode`*.

If you had done `currentNode.nextLink = null` instead of (basically) `currentNode = null` then that would be different:

- `currentNode = null` means "remove the address written on the piece of paper labelled `currentNode`.
- `currentNode.nextLink = null` means "go to the address written on the piece of paper labelled `currentNode`, there find a piece of paper labelled `nextLink` and remove the address written on it.

The first one just changes the reference `currentNode` and the second one actually changes the *object* pointed to by `currentNode`.

**Edit:** it seems your confusion stems from the debugging view where it says `currentNode = {StackWithLinkedList$Node@801}`. You seem to interpret this as "`currentNode` is the object `{StackWithLinkedList$Node@801}`", but that's not what it means.

`currentNode` **is never an object**. It can't be. Java variables/fields can't hold objects. So what that display **really** means is:  `currentNode` *currently references* the object represented as `{StackWithLinkedList$Node@801}`.

Comment: Yeah i tried out what you are suggesting, lets say i create Book book1 = new Book("Animal Farm"); and Book book2 = book1. as you pointed out, making book2 = null, doesn't make book1 null. But why if i change book2.setName("Alchemist") does book1 change?

Comment: Because `book2.setName()` does not change `book2`. Remember `book2` is just a reference to some object. Changing `book2` would mean it now pointed to another object or no object at all. Instead `book2.setName()` calls a method on the object referenced by book (which presumably changes something about that object). So `book2.setName(...)` changes something *about the object*. Since `book1` references *the same object* the change will also be visible via `book1`, but there's really only a single thing being changed.

Comment: Note that doing `currentNode.nextLink = null` would be roughly equivalent to `book2.setName("Alchemist")` in that they both affect a change to the *object* being referenced and do not chang the reference itself.

Comment: Finally i get, if i create Book Book3 = new Book("The Fountainhead") and book2 = book3; , the book2 previsouly pointing to book1 will change to book3 and book1 remains the same

Comment: Yes, exactly. The difference is 1. changing the reference and 2. changing the object that is being referenced. `book2 = book3` does #1, `book2.setName("Alchemist")` does #2.